# Create ("force") island in "gaps and island" problem

Tags: oracle, partition, gaps-and-islands

I have code that's partitioning my data for a gaps and island solution. The data itself is reporting on  user activity, time spent working, and idle time based on logged timestamps and activities. My code is working great, but every once in a while I have a user_id that logs a string of activities for one application, goes idle, then returns to the same application to log additional activity. Based on my current code, it looks like the user spent nearly two hours in one application when in reality there was significant downtime in the middle. I want to "force" the creation of an island, restarting the partition if there is a lapse of greater than 30 minutes between activities.

```
ACTIVITY_DATE | USER_ID | APPL_ID |  PR1  |  PR2
---------------------------------------------------

11/20/2020 10:55    A     9340         1    1
11/20/2020 10:55    A     9340         2    2
11/20/2020 10:58    A     9340         3    3
11/20/2020 10:58    A     9340         4    4
11/20/2020 10:59    A     9340         5    5
11/20/2020 13:09    A     9340         6    6
11/20/2020 13:09    A     9340         7    7
11/20/2020 13:10    A     9340         8    8
11/20/2020 13:10    A     9340         9    9
11/20/2020 17:12    A     8354        10    1
11/20/2020 17:14    A     8354        11    2
11/20/2020 17:14    A     8354        12    3
```

The final result needs to restart the partition for column PR2 at the sixth row in this example because the gap between logged activities exceeds 30min for the same appl_id:

```
ACTIVITY_DATE | USER_ID | APPL_ID |  PR1  |  PR2
---------------------------------------------------

11/20/2020 10:55    A     9340         1    1
11/20/2020 10:55    A     9340         2    2
11/20/2020 10:58    A     9340         3    3
11/20/2020 10:58    A     9340         4    4
11/20/2020 10:59    A     9340         5    5
11/20/2020 13:09    A     9340         6    1
11/20/2020 13:09    A     9340         7    2
11/20/2020 13:10    A     9340         8    3
11/20/2020 13:10    A     9340         9    4
11/20/2020 17:12    A     8354        10    1
11/20/2020 17:14    A     8354        11    2
11/20/2020 17:14    A     8354        12    3
```

Here's my current code:

```
    select activity_date, user_id, appl_id,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by activity_date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id, appl_id order by activity_date) rn2
    from 
    (select
    activity_date, user_id, appl_id, count(*)
    from mytable tt
    where
        user_id in ('A', 'B', 'C')
        and activity_date >= trunc(sysdate - 4,'DD')
        and activity_date <= trunc(sysdate - 3,'DD')
    group by
        activity_date, user_id, appl_id) tt
```

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Comment: @mathguy I'm using Toad Data Point 4.3.0.718 (64 bit)

Comment: I meant Oracle database version, not Toad version. If you don’t know, run select \* from v$version; and see what it says.

Comment: @mathguy Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT activity_date,
       user_id,
       appl_id,
       pr1,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, appl_id, mno ORDER BY pr1 )
         AS pr2
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY activity_date) AS pr1
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY user_id, appl_id
  ORDER     BY pr1
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( activities* last_activity )
  DEFINE activities AS
    NEXT(activity_date) <= LAST(activity_date) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
)
ORDER BY user_id, pr1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ACTIVITY_DATE, USER_ID, APPL_ID ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '10:55' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '10:55' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '10:58' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '10:58' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '10:59' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '13:09' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '13:09' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '13:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '13:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 9340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '17:12' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 8354 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '17:14' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 8354 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-20' + INTERVAL '17:14' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A', 8354 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ACTIVITY_DATE       | USER_ID | APPL_ID | PR1 | PR2
> :------------------ | :------ | ------: | --: | --:
> 2020-11-20 10:55:00 | A       |    9340 |   1 |   1
> 2020-11-20 10:55:00 | A       |    9340 |   2 |   2
> 2020-11-20 10:58:00 | A       |    9340 |   3 |   3
> 2020-11-20 10:58:00 | A       |    9340 |   4 |   4
> 2020-11-20 10:59:00 | A       |    9340 |   5 |   5
> 2020-11-20 13:09:00 | A       |    9340 |   6 |   1
> 2020-11-20 13:09:00 | A       |    9340 |   7 |   2
> 2020-11-20 13:10:00 | A       |    9340 |   8 |   3
> 2020-11-20 13:10:00 | A       |    9340 |   9 |   4
> 2020-11-20 17:12:00 | A       |    8354 |  10 |   1
> 2020-11-20 17:14:00 | A       |    8354 |  11 |   2
> 2020-11-20 17:14:00 | A       |    8354 |  12 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3091ddea26d1ef921c8d03861328d34d)*